# Linux package has been removed

Tags: php, installation, drush

Is there a way to get back the removed packages from my computer? I've made a big mistake. I am really eager to install php5-curl. I've type "sudo aptitude install php5-curl" based from what I found on the internet. I did read the message above that it will remove some packages to be able to install the php5-curl. Now, I lost phpmyadmin, php5 and drush. How to retrieve those packages? When I try to install them at the package manager, it always appear as file not found on the server. Please help.

Comment: What about migrating this question to Server Fault or Super User?

Comment: I've had various problems where distributions stop supporting one library or another. Try using `pecl` or `pear` to install the libraries instead? [More Information](https://pecl.php.net/)